# Printed strings are not displaying correctly in Python

Tags: python

In Python, im trying to display a st ring, but it is not coming up correctly.  My code is this:

```
print('Critical: '+ brokenFiles + '| number of errors = ',errorCount)
```

However, when the string is displayed, it comes up as:

```
('Critical: testoutput.txt .viminfo superoutput.txt Superoutput.txt .splunk output.txt output2.txt | number of errors = ', 7)
```

Ive tried making it single/double quotes,  and removing the commas causes the code to not compile since the errorCount variable is an integer.  What do I need to do to get this to work?

I would like the string displayed as:

```
Critical: testoutput.txt .viminfo superoutput.txt Superoutput.txt .splunk output.txt output2.txt | number of errors = 7
```

Comment: It is python2, isn't it? Then try without parenthesis.

Comment: What do you **want** it to look like?

Comment: Don't do this JavaScript-style string + string + string concatenation. Very inefficient. You'll have better results and won't get headaches over stuff like this if you just use the built-in [string formatting](https://pyformat.info/). (The docs on it are a little dense but that page has some examples of both old and new styles.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better practice would be using the `format` method of strings.

In Python 3:

```
print('Critical: {}| number of errors = {}' .format(brokenFiles, errorCount))
```

or the similar C-style `%` notation, for Python 2 (which will work in Py3, but which is deprecated and ugly:

```
print('Critical: %s| number of errors = %d' %(brokenFiles, errorCount))
```

Comment: If `brokenFiles` is a list, then `' '.join(brokenFiles)`